# How to check given string contains some specified special characters exists or not in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a input string when user enter data into the string then find out the string contains some specified (!@#$%) special characters are found or not. The following string values output like

```
 string str="Mn@";    --> true
 string str="m@*";    --> false
 string str="@Mn";    --> true
 string str="Mn&";    --> false
 string str="@";      --> true
 string str="M";      --> false
 string str="*";      --> false
 string str=" ";      --> false
 string str=" Mn";    --> false
 string str="M *";    --> false
 string str="m@ ";    --> false
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression, and put all the characters you want to search for into a character set:

```js
const pattern = /[!@#$%]/;
console.log(pattern.test('Mn@'));
console.log(pattern.test('@Mn'));
console.log(pattern.test('Mn&'));
console.log(pattern.test('@'));
console.log(pattern.test('M'));
console.log(pattern.test('*'));
```

For your new question, add negative lookahead for a space if you want to ensure the text doesn't contain a space:

```js
const pattern = /^(?!.* )[!@#$%]/;
console.log(pattern.test('Mn@'));
console.log(pattern.test('@Mn'));
console.log(pattern.test('Mn&'));
console.log(pattern.test('@'));
console.log(pattern.test('M'));
console.log(pattern.test('*'));
console.log(pattern.test(' '));
console.log(pattern.test(' Mn'));
console.log(pattern.test('M *'));
console.log(pattern.test('m@ *'));
```

Comment: /[!@#$%]/  this pattern not consider spaces. I want to check all special characters except  !@#$% these.

Comment: Best to state your problem upfront in the question, before answers start coming in - if you want to exclude text with spaces, negative lookahead for a space in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable function that will check that validation for you:

```js
var spChar = '!@#$%';

function isIncludeSpecialChar(stringVal){
  return spChar.split('').some((character) => stringVal.includes(character));
}
console.log(isIncludeSpecialChar('Mn@'));
console.log(isIncludeSpecialChar('@Mn'));
console.log(isIncludeSpecialChar('Mn&'));
console.log(isIncludeSpecialChar('@'));
console.log(isIncludeSpecialChar('M'));
console.log(isIncludeSpecialChar('*'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `test` and `match` functions in JS regex. test will give you if a character is present or not and match will give which character is present in the string

```js
var str1="Mn@";
console.log(/[!@#$%]/.test(str1))
console.log(str1.match(/[!@#$%]/))
```